# Correct HTML5 mark-up for floating logo, slogan and 2 navs

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I'm having difficulty understanding the recommended method for using sections, navs, headers and floating div containers in unison.

I have a network-wide nav followed by a site-wide nav, just like this Stack Overflow website.

Based on the following code...

```
<header>

    <!--Navigation menu for network:-->
    <section>
        <nav>
            <a href="#">Link</a>
            <a href="#">Link</a>
            <a href="#">Link</a>
        </nav>
    </section>

    <!--Navigation menu for site:-->
    <section>
        <div class="float-left">
            <h1>Logo Text</h1>
            <h2>Slogan Text</h2>
        </div>
        <nav class="float-right">
            <a href="#">Link</a>
            <a href="#">Link</a>
            <a href="#">Link</a>
        </nav>
    </section>

</header>
```

1. ...should I have both navs in their own sections within the one header as is or should I have two headers?
2. ...should my div.float-left be a section within a section?
3. ...overall, is there a better way to arrange my mark-up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML5 sectioning elements can be a bit challening, but I'll try to give you a solid walk-through:

**The `header` element**
This element can be used wherever you feel "introductory" content could live. The most logical example would be the header of a website that is shown on every page, but it can also be a header inside an article. Your use of `header` is fine.

**The `section` element**
This element is tricky and should really only be used to group content together. A good example would be if you have a news section on your homepage with a collection of latest news articles. Try reading this previous sentence out loud and you'll notice the words `section` and `article` who have a relation ;-)
Your use of the `section` element is **not** correct.
*Note: it's mandatory for a section to include a heading!*

**The `nav` element**
This element should exclusively be used for navigational items in two cases:

1. Website-wide navigation (like navigation in your global header)
2. Article navigation (e.g. to navigate between chapters in an article)

Don't use the `nav` element for anything else, it is really only useful for "main" navigations. In your case, it's fine, because both navs are very "global".
*Note: all `nav` elements should have a heading!*

To come back to your example, the following markup would be more appropriate and valid:

```
<header>

    <!-- Navigation menu for network: -->
    <nav>
        <h2>Network navigation</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <!-- Logo, title and slogan -->
    <img src="some/path" alt="Logo Description" class="logo">
    <h1>Website name</h1>
    <p class="slogan">Slogan text</p>

    <!-- Navigation menu for network: -->
    <nav>
        <h2>Site navigation</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

</header>
```

HTML5 Doctor has a lot of good resources on this as well! http://html5doctor.com/

Comment: Complete answer and therefore a complete solution. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your use of headings makes no sense in your example. <nav> is a `sectioning content` element, which means it has its own outline. Which in turn means your <h2> should be <h1>. Another problem:

Comment: You shouldn't use the global <h1> for the website name, but for the page title instead. <header> is not a sectioning element, so assuming it's under the body, that <h1>Website name</h1> applies to the entire page. Website names are fine inside the header, but don't use <h1> for them. Google can't categorize your site if every page is called "Website name".

Comment: Fair enough, it's probably better to not use a heading for it at all, instead use the h1 for just the main article's (page) title. Note: the original answer was written when the HTML5 outline was not yet fully developed. Back then the outline would have been correct, but I wouldn't recommend this approach anymore right now.